# Problems with My Simple JQuery Div Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple JQuery Div Slider, but it doesn't seem to be hiding the initial div or functioning properly.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="feature">
    <div class="feature_container">
        <div><p>Slide 1 Content</p></div>
        <div><p>Slide 2 Content</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JQuery code:

```
    <script>
  $(function(){
    $('.feature_container div:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('.feature_container :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('div').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.feature_container');},
        3000);
    })
  });
  </script>
```

Am I doing anything in the JQuery code here that's not allowed or incorrect?

Thanks in advance for any help- it's much appreciated! I would use a plugin too, but I'm really trying to figure out all of this by doing it by hand...

Comment: Why is this happening? http://jsfiddle.net/QDb5w/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just scrapped the above code and re-wrote it and this seems to be working:

```
    $('.feature_container div:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
    $('.feature_container div:first').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.feature_container');
}, 8000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a )

```
$('.feature_container div:gt(0)').hide();
```

To aid in finding these errors, just pop open Firefox's error panel. It'll throw and error right away and give you the line it's at.

Comment: Oops, sorry, that was an error in me posting the code snippet. It doesn't work with the ")" either.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problem pointed bout by @jpea, you still have another syntax problem.  The last line is extraneous and should be deleted.

Also your selector '.feature_container :first-child' translates to this: '.feature_container *:first-child' which means not only will the first DIV be faded, so will the P within it.  So you should change it to: '.feature_container div:first-child'.  So you end up with this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.feature_container div:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function() {
      $('.feature_container div:first-child').fadeOut()
          .next('div').fadeIn()
          .end().appendTo('.feature_container');},
      3000);
  });
</script>
```

So there isn't anything wrong with your jQuery usage. It was your JavaScript syntax and CSS that was causing your problems.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely an error on my part. However, I made the change and it still isn't working...